# $facebook->getUser() returning 0 always

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have already viewed most topics here and none of them works for me and I figured my problem may not be with the sdk because I use the same sdk for 2 apps in one app it is working fine and in the other it's always returning 0

```
require 'facebook/facebook.php';
$facebook   = new Facebook(array(
'appId'=>************,
'secret'=>'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
));

/*
Check if we have logged in user
*/
$uid    = $facebook->getUser();
var_dump($uid);
```

Can anyone think of a problem?

Comment: Have you send the user through the login flow before in the script?

Comment: Yes i have and they are redirected back with $_GET['code'] and $_GET['state']

Comment: What are ur settings looks like ? Ex: your canvas page URL, domain,etc.